# Using a NServiceBus to publish/receive messages locally

Tags: c#, command, messaging, nservicebus

Is it recommended to use NServiceBus (or any service bus library) solely for the purpose of publishing messages on the client side?

I've been looking at a handful of sample open source projects and they all seem to have one thing in common. All projects are publishing messages and getting consumers to handle the specific message (or command).

Essentially, I'm looking to decouple my actions by sending out messages and have a handler take care of it. This would all be done locally on the client.

Comment: I've always avoided this and used an EventAggregator for local pub/sub...but I'm curious about others' answers to this question...

Comment: Good call. I forgot to mention that I'm currently using Caliburn.Micro's event aggregator. The shortcoming for that small framework is that it doesn't create handlers. So say I had a standalone handler that handled a specific message, nothing would happen because that handler can't subscribe itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think NServiceBus and equivalent tools are too heavy on the client side and often requires extensive configuration.